# How to close a net.Server in Node.js tests?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, asynchronous, mocha.js

The example works find, but when I replace `server.listen(1234);` with `server.listen(1234, '127.0.0.1');` the test return the following error: "Error: Not running"

```
describe('Server', function() {
  it('should do something', function(done) {
    var server = new net.Server();
    server.listen(1234);

    // do something

    server.close();
    done();
  });
});
```

Can you explain to mw why?

Answer (score 0):

That is because `listen` is asynchronous. It just happens that in the case where no second parameter is given, it opens synchronously enough that `close` doesn't fail. For that matter, `close` is also async.

```
it('should do something', function(done) {
  var server = new net.Server();
  server.listen(1234, '127.0.0.1', function(){
    // do something

    server.close(done);
  });
});
```